Importing Module for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe gives version 4.0.4.0 instead of 4.0.4.1
I have a working PowerShell web scraping script using the latest Selenium client for .NET (4.27.0). I run this script on 2 laptops, both running Windows 11 23H2. Everything has been working fine. In version 4.24.0 Selenium migrated from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, and required me to download a number of other packages that were dependencies of System.Text.Json. One of those dependencies was 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'. In order to run the script both the NetStandard2.0 dll's from 'system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.6.0.0.nupkg' and 'system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.4.5.3.nupkg' were required. The 4.5.3 package actually contains the dll that corresponds to 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1.
Here is my issue. Yesterday I updated one of the Windows 11 23H2 laptops to Windows 11 24H2 but now when I try to run the script on that laptop the script fails with the following exception:
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManagerSerializerContext' threw an exception. 
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.MemoryExtensions.AsSpan(String text)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonEncodedText.Encode(String value, JavaScriptEncoder encoder)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManagerSerializerContext..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.BinaryPaths(String arguments)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.BinaryPaths()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverFinder.GetDriverPath()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver.GenerateDriverServiceCommandExecutor(DriverService service, DriverOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryConstructorInvoke(MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] arguments, Object[] originalArguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.ConstructorInvokeDotNet(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand.CallConstructor(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] args)


What the exception states is it can't find the Version 4.0.4.1 of 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'. However, I'm importing the Modules from a shared network location, so both laptops are using the exact same files for importation. On the Windows 11 24H2 machine I can see the file and file-version information matches the info on the Windows 11 23H2 laptop except for the Version number.
Windows 11 24H2
Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                             
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                             
Binary     4.0.4.0    System.Runtime.CompilerServices....                                                                              


(Get-Item (Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
4.6.28619.01 @BuiltBy: dlab14-DDVSOWINAGE069 @Branch: release/2.1 @SrcCode: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/7601f4f6225089ffb291dc7d58293c7bbf5c5d4f

(Get-Item (Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Path).VersionInfo.FileName
G:\Backups\Generics\Software\Selenium Clients\SeleniumModule_Current\Modules\Other\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll

(Get-Item (Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Path).VersionInfo.FileVersion
4.6.28619.01

Windows 11 23H2
Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                       
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                       
Binary     4.0.4.1    System.Runtime.CompilerServices....                                                                        


(Get-Item (Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
4.6.28619.01 @BuiltBy: dlab14-DDVSOWINAGE069 @Branch: release/2.1 @SrcCode: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/7601f4f6225089ffb291dc7d58293c7bbf5c5d4f

(Get-Item (Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Path).VersionInfo.FileName
G:\Backups\Generics\Software\Selenium Clients\SeleniumModule_Current\Modules\Other\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll

(Get-Item (Get-Module System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe).Path).VersionInfo.FileVersion
4.6.28619.01


I'm kind of at my wits end trying to figure out why the importation of the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll from the 4.5.3 package gives the wrong version number on the Windows 11 24H2 laptop. If anybody can point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative. For now my only viable option is to rollback the Windows update.

Well, I actually got it to work on the Windows 11 24H2 machine.
I was previously using the following command to import the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
Import-Module "$($ScriptPath)Modules\OldDependencies\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"

This actually worked on the Windows 11 23H2 machine.
On the updated laptop I changed the code to:
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$($ScriptPath)Modules\OldDependencies\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll")

This actually works on both laptops. Probably wouldn't have figured it out if I didn't read this post. Still not sure what the difference is though, but I'm glad it's working though.
